# Sharing an effectively immutable object between multiple threads

Tags: java, concurrency

Will the updated values in the hashmap below will reflect in the reader threads(the threads will not modifiy the state of the hashMap)?
What if `ConcurrentHashMap` is used instead?

```
public class SharedDataTest {

  private static class SomeWork implements Runnable {
    private Map<String, String> dataTable;

    public SomeWork(Map<String, String> dataTable) {
      this.dataTable = dataTable;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
      //do some stuff with dataTable
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<String, String> dataTable = new HashMap<String, String>();
    dataTable.put("someKey","someValue");

    Runnable work1 = new SomeWork(dataTable);
    Runnable work2 = new SomeWork(dataTable);

    new Thread(work1).start();
    new Thread(work2).start();

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all initialization of the map is done before starting the threads, then there is no need for additional synchronization. The start of a thread will act as a memory barrier, and anything happened before that thread start will be visible to that thread.

Note that if you change the map after threads start, then there is no guarantee on whether or if the threads will see that change.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will reflect but there may be inconsistency depending on you you do on your `run()` method because you are not synchronizing externally. Use `Collections.synchronizedMap(map)`  or better use a `ConcurrentHashMap` which will provide you thread safety for free

```
public SomeWork(Map<String, String> dataTable) {
  this.dataTable = Collections.synchronizedMap(dataTable);
}
```

Check the documentation of HashMap which asks to synchronize externally in case of concurrency

> - **Note that this implementation is not
>     synchronized.**  * If multiple threads access a hash map
>     concurrently, and at least one of  * the threads modifies the map
>     structurally, it *must* be  * synchronized externally.  (A
>     structural modification is any operation  * that adds or deletes one
>     or more mappings; merely changing the value  * associated with a key
>     that an instance already contains is not a  * structural
>     modification.)  This is typically accomplished by  * synchronizing on
>     some object that naturally encapsulates the map.

Answer (score 0):

It will be better to use a `ConcurrentHashMap` rather than externally synchronize the map.

```
public class SharedDataTest {

  private static class SomeWork implements Runnable {
    private Map<String, String> dataTable;

    public SomeWork(Map<String, String> dataTable) {
      this.dataTable = dataTable;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
      //do some stuff with dataTable
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<String, String> dataTable = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>();
    dataTable.put("someKey","someValue");

    Runnable work1 = new SomeWork(dataTable);
    Runnable work2 = new SomeWork(dataTable);

    new Thread(work1).start();
    new Thread(work2).start();
  }
}
```